# Sticky footer + hover question

Tags: jquery, css

Two questions:

1. I want my footer at the bottom of [my page](http://johanberntsson.se/dev/fysiosteo/). Seems to work, except in chrome. Did I miss something?
2. How do I make my menu hover function keep the highlight on the main menu when I'm hovering its children? (Keep the green background-color).

Comment: can you provide some code as well ?

Comment: How do I solve the biggest problem of life, If I do not know what the probelm is? (The Code Mate!)

Comment: You'll need to include some markup and css for us to have any idea how to help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. if those two questions are unrelated to each other, they would be better if they were asked separately. Secondly, we really can't tell if you've missed something or not if you don't show us any of your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post relevant code with your posts whenever possible, it makes it very hard to answer otherwise.

Comment: Haha, this is the biggest WTF question. Surprised it isn't showered with downvotes :D

Comment: Forgot to post the url to my page, sorry :) Edited question.

Comment: The footer Works fine in Chrome 12.0.742.122. Sticks to the bottom. You want the green background-color on :hover only?

Comment: The footer makes a scroll for me in chrome, on pages that doesnt have much content. Yea, on hover is enough. Thanks

Comment: @John: Please use @ along with the name. I did not get this comment in my inbox. What version of chrome are you using and the scroll is Hoz or Ver?

Comment: @Jawad ok, chrome v 12.0, its vertical. On the startpage for example, youll see a scrollbar.

Comment: @Johan: I tried to replicate your problem but don't see any scrollbar even when there is minimum content - http://i55.tinypic.com/e6oiyo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The demo link you posted seems to have both the problems you mentioned already fixed! Checked with chrome and your footer is securely stuck to the bottom of the page and your nav items are lighting up when you hover over the sub nav items.